# Use Less than and greater than workflow criteria with text field

Tags: workflow, custom-field, process-builder, text, number

I have an issue. A custom text field is created to store survey score number. Now I have to setup a flow rule when score is less than 5. A case should be created and assign to account owner.

My problem is when I tried put criteria survey score less than 5, I am not getting less than greater than option because it’s a text field. I tried to change data type but this field is using on account page as roll up summary and also use in multiple calculation.

So if I changed all data wipe out and I have to upload it again. It may be possible that I can loss the data.

Please help me to put less than or greater than criteria in text field so I can use it is process builder. I don’t want to change data type.

Comment: the only option I can suggest is to call apex method from your process builder and then write custom logic to handle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the formula "**VALUE**".

```
VALUE(text)
```

Converts a text string that represents a number to a number

Then you can use greater/less than operators.

Example:  `VALUE(text_1__c) < 5`

**EDIT 1:** If formula output is boolean.

```
IF(VALUE(text_1__c) < 5, TRUE, FALSE)
```

**EDIT 2:** Use mathematical operators and logic operators as per your requirement. Examples here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm

Comment: It's not working. getting error expected text getting number. I need to use this formula for process builder.

Comment: What is your formula field now?

Comment: It's a text field.

Comment: please raise a new question if you have more problems (or at least update your question).  Your question states only about conversion from Text to number, which I have already answered.

Comment: Yes, But when I tried to put the formula. I am getting error " Formula result is data type (Boolean), Incompatible with expected data type (text)

Comment: Updated answer. try

Comment: Hi, formula is accepted by process builder but rule trigger on both situation if field less than 5 or field greater than 5. However I put only less than 5 in criteria.

Comment: In that case, you can just change to IF(VALUE(text_1__c) < 5 || VALUE(text_1__c) > 5, TRUE, FALSE)